# How to connect to Windows XP(Guest OS) of the VirtualBox from Ubuntu using tsclient

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, guest-os, tsclient

I have Ubuntu OS and running Windows XP on Virtual Box of Ubuntu as my guest OS.

I wanted to know how can I be able to connect to my guest OS - Windows XP of Virtual Box using tsclient.

When I try to connect using RDP protocol of tsclient I am getting following error message:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox do you use? The OSE (free) or the binary version from Oracle? The latter supports RDP access.

Comment: VirtualBox OSE(free) v. 3.2.1

Comment: The OSE version does not have the in-built RDP support. The binary version of VirtualBox supports 1. USB devices and 2. RDP. Therefore, if you insist to use the OSE version, you will have to do some extra work to setup the RDP server on the guest and access from Ubuntu through the internal IP address.

Comment: From Virtual Box **4.0** OSE you need to install the PUEL Oracle Extension Pack: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 2):

I have same configuration. And I setted my VBox as a (terminal)service, and it runs in background.

This configuration is multi-step, no too easy, if you are a beginner. But I did it...

**VirtualBox**

Start here, at first, you have to set Network type, to **Bridge mode**.
Look at here, in **Attached to:** section:
[image: bridge mode]

Then, your DHCP client will handle your XP as a new computer in LAN, so it will give a new IP to your virtual XP. That IP will be your RDP host. To check that IP, click on network icon near the clock, and the details tab will show your IP, if your DHCP works fine!

**XP - guest machine**

Here, you should enable RDP server mode and multi user login system, see that tutorial [here](http://www.raneri.it/blog/eng/index.php/2006/04/24/windows-xp-multiuser-remote-desktop/).

Image example for STEP 5: [image: gpedit.msc]

**Ubuntu - host system**

At first, I give you a method, how can you start your guest machine in background.

Hit [Alt] + [F2], type in: `VBoxHeadless -startvm "NameOfVirtualMachine"`. *You may add it to (System > Preferences >) Startup applications.*

*To check the status, start your VBox controller, and it will display: Running...*

If you want to shut it down, you should log in remotely to guest, and right click on task bar(or [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Del] if it works), then Task manager. In the task manager, you can click on Shut down > Power off; click yes, if it asks you about the restart problem.

Before you connect to your XP, you may play with resolution, settings, sound config, shared drive, not all options will work!

**If I forget something, please ask me!**

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in the tutorial link you provided about hacking Windows XP, in the step 5 I could not find Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Terminal Services parameter in gpedit.msc. It doesn't exist. I did the rest but had no any success. Still having exactly the same problem and getting the same error message.

Comment: I attached an image, try to find it! You haven't allowed to log in, so maybe after this settings. Sorry it is in Hungarian...

Comment: Thanks but in my case it finishes with Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates, i.e. there is no Windows Components nor Terminal Services.

Comment: Have you got XP pro, or home? I think the home hasn't got this feature...

Comment: I have XP Pro SP3

Comment: ok, than you have allowed to login only with one client at the same time. Enable the Remote login in(Step 6), and try to log in; BUT you have to start the machine in Headless mode, or log out in normal mode!
If everything works on guest OS, your client might have some issues, like sound, img settings. Try to changes settings befor logging in!